# Css can't be loaded when i send data from a servlet

Tags: css, servlets, httpresponse, response.redirect, requestdispatcher

My CSS Stylesheets don't load any JSP page 
if i send any data to the JSP page the CSS don't load . 
and when i only use response.sendRedirect( ) without data the CSS can be loaded correctly

```
List<Specialite> specialite = new ArrayList<>();
Query query = session.createQuery("from Specialite");
specialite = query.list();
t.commit();
request.setAttribute("specialite_list", specialite);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/Jsp/reg_enseignant.jsp").forward(request, response);
response.sendRedirect("//localhost:8086/GestionPfe/Jsp/reg_enseignant.jsp");
```

If I don't send that ArrayList the CSS appears correclty ,
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should works :) finally

```
   List<Specialite> specialite = new ArrayList<>();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Specialite");
    specialite = query.list();
    t.commit();
    request.setAttribute("specialite_list", specialite);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Jsp/reg_enseignant.jsp").forward(request, response);
```